# Condition on date from MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time

I need some help on apparently a simple problem but i cant figure out how it works properly

I have dates stored in MySQL such as 01/02/2012 07:40:23

this date is extracted to php in $list['timeadded'] variable.

I need to check if the difference between current date and that date is less or equal to 7 days then I will display the difference in term of number of days, otherwise echo closed.

Can somebody help me figuring this out ?

Thanks

Comment: First, stop storing your dates as strings. Use MySQL datetime type.

Comment: they are actually in datime format they are not strings

Answer (score 0):

<s>I think this may do what you need (ass this to your query)</s>

WHERE CURDATE() >= STR_TO_DATE(`datecol`, "%c/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s") - INTERVAL 7 DAY

**PHP Version**

```
$list['timeadded'] = '01/02/2012 07:40:23';
$dt1 = new DateTime($list['timeadded']);

$dt2 = new DateTime();
$dt2->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));

$interval = $dt1->diff($dt2);
echo $interval->format('%d days');
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/5b1MZ)

You can get the number of days use `$interval->d`

Comment: I am actually looking for a way to do it via php not in the sql query

Answer (score 0):

In your query, I would use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() on that field. So:

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timeadded) AS timeadded
FROM `your_table`
```

Then, with this result, I would subtract it from the current date. So:

```
$difference = (time()-$list['timeadded']);
```

I now have the time difference, in seconds. You can format this as days, minutes or hours using `date()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the datediff function described here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php or you can write your own function to calculate the difference between two dates by converting them to a unix timestamp, then calculating the number of seconds between the two and then calculate the number of days.

```
function numberOfDays($datecol) {
     $dateSeconds = strtotime($datecol);
     $now = time();
     $seconds = $now - $dateSeconds;
     //calcualte the number of days 
     $days = $seconds / (60 * 60 * 24);
     return $days
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I now you are looking for PHP solution but you can do this job in SQL directly in a efficient way and you can avoid check in php. Take a look of the Demo URL and check the output.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca91e/26

Table:

```
create table t (id int(3), date varchar(40));
insert into t values (1, '25/03/2013 07:40:23'), 
(2, '26/03/2013 07:40:23'),
(3, '20/03/2013 07:40:23');
```

SQL:

```
SELECT id, date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS CurrDate,
date_format(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS MyDate,
if(datediff(date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'), date_format(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'))<=7,
datediff(date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'), date_format(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')), 'closed') AS Text
FROM t;
```

Output:

```
ID  CURRDATE                MYDATE                 TEXT
1   2013-03-29 12:00:00     2013-03-25 07:40:23     4
2   2013-03-29 12:00:00     2013-03-26 07:40:23     3
3   2013-03-29 12:00:00     2013-03-20 07:40:23     closed
```